# Variable selection - Decide for family, link, etc. after or before?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, feature-selection, model-selection, poisson-distribution, unsupervised-learning

This may be a dumb question but I was wondering about the appropriate chronology to
adjust model parameters in a glm when performing variable selection.

Suppose, one has a set of predictors $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$.
The dependent variable $Y$ is a count variable, so either poisson or negative-binomial distribution are appropriate. The user decides for poisson regression and obtains the final model $Y$ ~ $x_1 + x_4$ using forward selection. When checking assumptions, they discover that the model is overdispersed - which would make a negative-binomial distribution more appropriate.

After variable selection, would it be appropriate to apply the usual steps that are typically used in the face of violated assumptions? For example, trying a different family or transforming predictors. It seems somewhat arbitrary to choose a family before variable selection, as it depends on the predictors in the model. On the other hand, deciding for parameters after looking at the model feels like effect picking to me.